# Jquery to identify break, tabs in contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following div in **HTML**:

```
<div id="content" 
spellcheck="false" 
contenteditable="true" 
autocapitalization="off" 
autocorrection="off" 
autocomplete="off" 
></div>
```

I want to replace every break, tab with a **string**:

```
$(function(){
    $('#start').click(function() {

        var str = $('#content').text();
        str = str.replace(/\r?\n/g, 'string');
        str = encodeURIComponent(str);
        str = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');

    });
});
```

However this example dosent work! The str must be called with **text** and not **html**. I'we probably tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question, how do you use the div for input.
When you write manually into, each line break means a new paragraph.
When you paste text with tabs and line breaks, the tabs become `<nbsp>` and the line breaks `<br>`, how you can see, when you alert `$('#content').html()`.
Maybe you should use the textarea instead...

Comment: the reason i dont use textarea is because it has to return in the same div text whit style, and textarea dose'nt allow styling

Comment: I understand, but then you will have a lot of work with the interpretation. Do you really need to interpret the input? Look at the "post answer" here - it is done using textarea and rendered to a div...